# “I’ve a cold” vs “I have a cold”—are both correct?

Tags: contractions

Would the sentence “I’ve a cold” be correct? I’m wondering if contractions can always be used in place of the original words.

Answer (score 1):

You can contract "I have" to "I've" and likewise say we've, you've, they've etc, but doing this when 'have' is the main verb is more common on British English than American.

> In British or American English? A Handbook of Word and Grammar
>   Patterns (2006), the linguist John Algeo writes that the use of “I’ve”
>   with the contracted primary verb is over five times more frequent in
>   the UK than in the US.

[When ‘I have’ becomes ‘I’ve’](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2018/05/i-have.html)

Comment: I can confirm this sounds unusual to an American ear, but it's true that it's more common in British English. +1

Comment: It sounds normal in BrE; but even more common is _I've got a cold_.

Comment: That's the common cold.

Comment: @RonaldSole No, it could also be the same as *I've (got / caught) a chill*, which has nothing to do with illness, but only with temperature.

Comment: I tend to interpret a "chill" (the kind you catch) like Cambridge Dictionary: chill noun (ILLNESS)
 
[ C ]
a slight fever:
Don't go out with wet hair, you might catch a chill.